# MySQL help making query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to display the consumption of products for 6 months.

My table `Consumption` is made as:

```
int ID_Conso
int ID_Product
int Quantity_Conso
int Month_Conso
int Year_COnso
```

there is 1 record/1 product/1 month as shown in picture below

[image]

the query I want to write for my view must show the result as :

[image]

Here is my query :

```
      SELECT c.id_Product,
         t1.conso1, 
         t2.conso2, 
         t3.conso3, 
         t4.conso4, 
         t5.conso5, 
         t6.conso6
  FROM Consumption c,
     (SELECT quantity_conso as "conso1" 
            FROM `consumption` 
            WHERE year= Year(Now()) and month = 1) t1,
     (SELECT quantity_conso as "conso2" 
            FROM `consumption` 
            WHERE year= Year(Now()) and month = 2) t2,
     (SELECT quantity_conso as "conso3" 
            FROM `consumption` 
            WHERE year= Year(Now()) and month = 3) t3,
     (SELECT quantity_conso as "conso4" 
            FROM `consumption` 
            WHERE year= Year(Now()) and month = 4) t4,
     (SELECT quantity_conso as "conso5" 
            FROM `consumption` 
            WHERE year= Year(Now()) and month = 5) t5,
     (SELECT quantity_conso as "conso6" 
            FROM `consumption` 
            WHERE year= Year(Now()) and month = 6) t6
```

this query displays all the records for all the `id_product` (doesn't display `null` if one record is missing)

I have tried to use if exist but without success.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/52315966/2469308
It should work for you. Instead of `null`, it will get `0`, which I believe should be workable with!

Comment: It is a concise version and efficient as well. If it works for you, consider upvoting and accepting it as answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use aggregation function [SUM](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_sum.asp) with [IF](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_if.asp), and `GROUP BY` on `Id_Product`. Try the following query:

```
SELECT 
  Id_Product, 
  SUM(IF(Month_Conso = 1, Quantity_Conso, 0)) AS QtyConso_Month1, 
  SUM(IF(Month_Conso = 2, Quantity_Conso, 0)) AS QtyConso_Month2, 
  SUM(IF(Month_Conso = 3, Quantity_Conso, 0)) AS QtyConso_Month3, 
  SUM(IF(Month_Conso = 4, Quantity_Conso, 0)) AS QtyConso_Month4, 
  SUM(IF(Month_Conso = 5, Quantity_Conso, 0)) AS QtyConso_Month5, 
  SUM(IF(Month_Conso = 6, Quantity_Conso, 0)) AS QtyConso_Month6 
FROM Consumption 
GROUP BY Id_Product 
ORDER BY Id_Product ASC
```

Comment: And the "null"?

Comment: It can return 0 instead of null. Is `null` necessary ?

Comment: @TheImpaler do you really need `NULL` instead of zero ? If yes, query can be adjusted very easily to do the same

Comment: I don't really. It's up to @Jlo to decide if he/she wants them. Just wanted to point out the "small" difference. In any case, I find your solution concise and sufficient. Upvoting.

Comment: No it's OK, 0 is fine for me, thank you very much for your answer (I still get a syntaxe error but will find the solution) :-)

Comment: it works ! fantastic. 
I just had to add parenthesis for the IF, as follow : SUM(IF(Month_Conso = 1, Quantity_Conso, 0)) Thank you very much Madhur